# Target an ID within an ID

Tags: css, wordpress

Within the `.admin-bar` of my website, lies a blue `#expander` in the top right corner that shows up on most templates of our website. I would like to target the `#expander` and set it do `display: none;` (or something to make it disappear) only for this page template: `.page-template-default #main` { (my main template page)

Therefore, and to put it in other words, I think I have to target an ID (`.page-template-default #main`) within an ID (`.admin-bar #expander`) in order to make the blue expander disappear. I am having trouble formatting this in my CSS. Can someone please show me how?

Can be seen here: http://visualicreative.com/general/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should only have to target the ID since it is unique (or needs to be anyway).

Comment: What @putvande said; just writing a new line with `#expander {display: none;}` in your CSS should work. If not, you probably just need to get more specific with your selectors.

Comment: @putvande and tylerh, if you read the question it says he only wants to hide that element on a certain page.  If you just use `#expander` it will hide it on every page,  Jeffrey, can you not just target it using `.page-template-default #main #expander`?

Comment: You should really look at my answer..

Comment: @tylerH thank you for your support. I can make the blue expander disappear when I write this code:

    admin-bar #expander, .admin-bar #navigation {
    top: -30px;
    }

However, this takes away the blue expander on all of my pages. I do not want that. Instead, I only want the blue expander to be taken away on this template
    .page-template-default #main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not dynamically change an elements CSS after the page has loaded using your style sheet. You must use a client-sided language such as JavaScript/jQuery.

One possible solution is that you can check for a specific URL, and inside change your elements CSS.

```
if (document.URL == "YOUR_PAGES_URL") { 
    $("#expander").css("display", "none");
}
```

This way if you are on the "template" you want you can hide the element `#expander`.

I highly recommend you read up on JavaScript as it seems that you may be unfamiliar with functionality that client-sided scripting languages have to offer.